# Installing PyV8 on Heroku

Tags: python, svn, heroku

I'm trying to install PyV8 for my Heroku app.

At first I tried adding it to the requirements, but I got an error because heroku don't have svn installed. I managed to find the lib on some git repo, but apparently the setup itself tries to access svn.

So.. Is it possible to install svn on Heroku? or to get PyV8 in some other way?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to install svn on heroku, and PyV8. Check out this post http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/using-vulcan-to-build-binary-dependencies-on-heroku/ for help.